# NO LOGINS: System going down ... stuck and won't shutdown

Tags: macos, ssh, shutdown, drobo

I issued a remote SSH shutdown command to a headless Mac server. However, the server is not shutting down and I can no longer access the server with SSH, I get this message:

> NO LOGINS: System going down at 08:16

This was nearly 20 minutes ago. What can I do now that the machine won't shut down and I cannot login?

I realize I can push the power button, but I have some Drobos attached that could loose data if don't gracefully shut down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strangely, the server did finally shutdown a few hours later. I verified the time zones are in-sync so not sure what the root cause was.

Answer (score 12):

Go to Finder. In the menu bar click **Go**, select **Go to folder**, type `/etc/` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. In the opened window find the "nologin" file and delete it. It's fixed.

Comment: This worked for me.  No idea how or why that `nologin` file appeared.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know your situation exactly, but it happened to me that when i typed `shutdown -k` in terminal, the `nologin` file was created and filled with the comment after `shutdown -k`.