# MacBook does not shutdown from Terminal: "NO LOGINS: System going down at 14:54"

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, shutdown

My MacBook is suddenly not working normally. I cannot restart or shut it down. When I try to use terminal it shows:

> NO LOGINS: System going down at 14:54

I logged out of my Apple ID and logged in again. However, it’s still not working. I cannot use any buttons or applications. I only can use Siri to help start the applications. Anyone know how to fix it?

Many thanks!

[image]

Comment: Any Computer including macs have a physical start (and shutdown) button. Hold ir for roughly 5 seconds and your MacBook will force shutdown. Often, a reboot fixes many things.

Comment: Also, what happens when you hit the little apple icon in the top menu? Can you shutdown from there? Can you open activity monitor and see if any app is not responding?

Comment: Thx, when I hit the icon I can see the shutdown option but it won’t shutdown. So, it looks like a fake one. I can use any applications though Siri normally. my MacBook doesn’t have a physical button to shutdown.

Comment: I tired to run out of the battery, then restart. It becomes fine now!

Comment: Your MacBook definitely has a physical button shotdwon button! It is the same as the start button and you definitely need that one! If its a MacBook with Touchbar, then the button is the fingerprint reader. Otherwise it will be marked with the start logo: https://www.google.de/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2F9to5mac.com%2F2019%2F04%2F29%2Fpower-button-macbook%2F&psig=AOvVaw2ju4tJ7mpAzTKlEke26nvM&ust=1642587448309000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=2ahUKEwjNq5ycibv1AhU1YPEDHTRBAnYQr4kDegUIARCyAg or https://tinyurl.com/2p9d3shc

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If you hold the power button long enough (maybe its more than 5 seconds, maybe ten) your MacBook **is going to** shutdown.

Comment: Thank you anyway! I mean the power button is also not working.

Comment: How are you turning on your computer then?

Comment: charge my computer for a while

Answer (score 1):

This can be fixed using the solution from this question:

[NO LOGINS: System going down ... stuck and won't shutdown](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/233336/no-logins-system-going-down-stuck-and-wont-shutdown)

Which is:
Go to Finder. In the menu bar click Go, select Go to folder, type /etc/ and press Enter. In the opened window find the "nologin" file and delete it.

Hope it helps future users!

Comment: Please [edit] and quote the relevant parts of the link in your answer